# Asp.Net Core Route Default Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a Asp.net Core application and i use a route like this.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Address",
    template: "adress-info/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Address", action = "Index" }
);
```

My url helper generate wrong url addres if i don't use default parameter. 
For example

```
//This is generate right url. http://localhost/address-info
@Url.RouteUrl("Address",new {action="Index"})

//i expect generate same url as up but it's generate http://localhost/address-info/anotherAction
@Url.RouteUrl("Address")
```

Why doesn't apply MapRoute's default action? What is the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Where did the string `anotherAction` come from? I'd expect your second example to make `http://localhost/address-info/Index`.

Comment: it is an action in the same controller(Address controller). "public IActionResult GuestAddress()". the helper generate  "http://localhost/address-info/guestaddress"